# How to skip some portion of code in onresume() based on if onactivityresult() is called

Tags: android

I have a fairly simple query. In my app, I need to do some processing in onresume(). However, when I return from a particular activity, I need to skip that portion of code. As onActivityResult() is always called before onResume(), I assume I can set some condition in OnActivityResult() so that the code skips in onResume(). However, I cant think of what can be done for this. Please suggest me something to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some boolean variable in onActivityResult, and check for it onResume(); Here is example:

```
private boolean isReturned = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 111){
        isReturned = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(isReturned){
        // make something
    } else{
        // normal mode
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to set back `isReturned = false`, when `onResume` called